# How can i avoid generator error in python coding

Tags: python, for-loop, generator

```
pizza={
       'crust':'thick',
       'toppings':['Mushroom','cheese','pineapple'],
       }

for i in pizza['toppings']:
    print(i)


print(x for x in pizza['toppings'])
```

when it comes to the last line, a message showed as "<generator object  at 0x00000216EDBA7D48>"
rather than the outcome I expected. I was hoping the result is the same as above-printed in a "for loop"

Comment: `for thing in things: do_stuff_with(thing)` and `do_stuff_with(thing for thing in things)` mean completely different things. You should not expect to be able to replace one with the other.

Comment: Have you tried: `print(*pizza['toppings'])` or `print(*pizza['toppings'], sep='\n')` ?

Comment: thank you very much Monica, I am new to python, I thought they were the same, as for some situations the outcome is identical. If I may, would you please explain a little about those two? i.e. for thing in things do_stuff_with(thing) and do_stuff_with(thing for thing in things)

Answer (score 0):

Your code actually creates a `generator` object.
You can use squared brackets if you want to have a `list` instead of `generator`

```
print([x for x in pizza['toppings']])
```

**Output**:

```
['Mushroom', 'cheese', 'pineapple']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print(*pizza['toppings'], sep = ", ")
```

**Output** :

```
Mushroom, cheese, pineapple
```